# Handling errors in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using WPF MVVM im one of my project. I have a datagrid which I bind to list of objects.

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfValues}" Margin="5,38"
```

In my view model class I have a property for ListOfValues

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassA> ListOfValues
        {
            get { return listOfValues; }
            set
            {
                listOfValues= value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ListOfValues");
            }
        }
```

In my ClassA I have three properties.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public long No { get; set; }        
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

In the grid user can only enter a value for the Amount filed.I want to validate whether user enters valid decimal value for that filed.

Suggest me a place where I can catch the execption. I try to handle it at the close of the window. But if the user enters invalid value its not saved in the data context of the view. Also I tried to validate it in the setter of ClassA its not hit the setter of the value.

Comment: how do you do the validation? do you use IDataErrorInfo Interface?

Comment: no I am not using IDataErrorInfo

Comment: I would suggest you to implement IDataErrorInfo Interface and INotifyPropertyChanged Interface for you ClassA.

Comment: and then you can check for an error whenever you want ie when closing the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could attack this problem from a different angle... how about stopping the users from entering any non-numerical characters into the `TextBox` in the first place?

You can do this using the `PreviewTextInput` and `PreviewKeyDown` events... attach handlers to the `TextBox` in question and add this code into them:

```
public void TextCompositionEventHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    // if the last pressed key is not a number or a full stop, ignore it
    return e.Handled = !e.Text.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c) || c == '.');
}

public void PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // if the last pressed key is a space, ignore it
    return e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
}
```

If you want to take a bit of time for re-usability, you can put this into an `Attached Property`... it's great to be able to add this functionality with a property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Price}" Attached:TextBoxProperties.IsDecimalOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Hi, its a column in a data grid not a text box

Comment: The `Textbox` just shows how I use this functionality when it is wrapped in an `Attached Property`. However, you can add a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, define a `DataTemplate` for it with a `TextBox` in it and attach these handlers to that `TextBox`. See the [DataGridTemplateColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx) page at MSDN for more information.

Comment: I have restrict the inputs using PreviewTextInput action. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your data type classes. You can find a full tutorial about it [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/), but in basic terms, this is how it works.

We need to add an `indexer` to each class:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;
        if (columnName == "FirstName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                result = "Please enter a First Name";
        }
        if (columnName == "LastName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                result = "Please enter a Last Name";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

> Taken from linked tutorial

In this `indexer`, we add our validation requirements for each property in turn. You *can* add multiple requirements per property:

```
        if (columnName == "FirstName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName)) result = "Please enter a First Name";
            else if (FirstName.Length < 3) result = "That name is too short my friend";
        }
```

Whatever you return in the `result` parameter is used as the error message in the UI. In order for this to work, you need to add to your `binding` values:

```
Text="{Binding FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan. Your code wirks fine for me if the column type is string. But for decimal column it shows only red color border.